# HTML first file in file selector doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload, filereader

All I'm trying to do is let the user upload image files and display them one by one, but for some reason the first file in the list of images I upload never works. The image data is undefined. No errors show up.

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/59q8f3bh/

Try to upload only one image, and then multiple images.

My HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple accept="image/*">
  <button type="submit" onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
  <img src="">

  <script src="js/upload.js"></script>
</body>
```

My JS:

```
function upload() {
  var selected = document.getElementById('image');

  for (var i = 0; i < selected.files.length; i++) {
    var img = selected.files[i];
    var imgData;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      imgData = reader.result;
    }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgData;
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the fiddle with the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ShaneCreedon/bjt0mLkd/5/).

The event you were waiting for with "load" is asynchronous and takes some time, therefore, 
when your program flows down and hits this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgData;
```

The result is undefined because `imgData` hasn't been set yet, due to the asynchronous nature of the "load" event.

The solution is to just move the img setter into the event callback.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event occurs asynchronously, you need to use the result in the callback function.

```
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      imgData = reader.result;
      document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = imgData;
    }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    alert(i);
  }
```

But you're only going to see the last image, since there's only one `<img>` element.